# How can i use the Twig template engine without modifying the php.ini?

Tags: php, twig

i want to use Twig, for a small project, that i don't need MVC.

is it necessary to install the Twig extension on php.ini?

Can i use it standalone like the Smarty template engine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just follow [Installing the Twig PHP package](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/installation.html#installing-the-twig-php-package), NOT Installing the C extension.